Iterating operations over function arguments in python
I have a function which accepts 7 input, each of them could be a scalar (float), a list, or a numpy array. For subsequent calculations, I want to convert them all to numpy arrays.
import numpy as np

def my_function(period,mw,rjb,soft_site=0,stiff_site=0,fault_normal=0,fault_reverse=0):
    period = np.array(period)
    mw = np.array(mw)
    rjb = np.array(rjb)
    soft_site = np.array(soft_site)
    stiff_site = np.array(stiff_site)
    fault_normal = np.array(fault_normal)
    fault_reverse = np.array(fault_reverse)

This is how I'm doing it. Is there a way to loop over the arguments rather than repeatedly calling the np.array() method because that would also make it compatible with variable number of arguments.

Can you take the arguments as an iterable object?

The arguments may be of different size, for example, one of them is a scalar while the other is an nd array. I could perhaps pass the arguments as a dictionary or use the **args, but prefer to have the arguments specified individually.

prefer to have the arguments specified individually Then no, there is no way to iterate over them.

This question is similar to: Get a list/tuple/dict of the arguments passed to a function?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@JohnGordon you can iterate over the arguments passed to a function using locals() or using the inspect module.

@jodag the post you mentioned deals with getting a dict of the arguments, and locals() method does that. One can iterate over the keys and values of the dictionary, but I need to change the values of the dictionary. I'm not how I can achieve this with the locals() method.

locals() will allow you to get the name and value for each argument, but will not be able to change the value using locals().

@Booboo @rajeshrupakhety locals() or inspect can be used to get the names of the arguments and iterate over them. You could set them with exec now that you have their names. That said, if you want to have explicitly named parameters, this also implies that they should be treated explicitly. The approach OP is currently using in the question makes the most sense to me and is easy to follow. Clarity is more important than saving some keystrokes IMO.

While I don't think there's anything wrong with your current approach, I think a decorator may give you the behavior you want without being too cryptic or unpythonic
import numpy as np

def args_to_ndarray(f):
    """ decorator converts all args and keyword args to numpy arrays """
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        args = [np.asarray(arg) for arg in args]
        kwargs = {key: np.asarray(value) for key, value in kwargs.items()}
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    
    return wrapper

@args_to_ndarray     # <--- decorator ensures all args converted to np.ndarrays
def my_function(a, b, c):
    print(f'type(a): {type(a)}')
    print(f'type(b): {type(b)}')
    print(f'type(c): {type(c)}')

my_function(1, 2, 3)

when run, this prints
type(a): <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
type(b): <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
type(c): <class 'numpy.ndarray'>

Note that if you use default arguments they will not be included in the decorator wrapper.

Use the kwargs option and loop through the keywords resulting in a dictionary with your arrays.
def my_function2(period, mw, rjb, **kwargs):
    period = np.array(period)
    mw = np.array(mw)
    rjb = np.array(rjb)
    for k in kwargs:
        kwargs[k] = np.array(kwargs[k])
    return kwargs

x = my_function2(2,[1,2,3],'1234', soft_site=0,stiff_site=0,fault_normal=0,fault_reverse=0)

print(x)

Results in:
{'soft_site': array(0), 'stiff_site': array(0), 'fault_normal': array(0), 'fault_reverse': array(0)}


This requires that an argument such as soft_site be passed as a keyword argument while the OP's code has no such requirement. You also lose default values for arguments such as soft_site when not explicitly passed.

I was answering the core element of his question, not giving a complete production answer, which can easily be resolved using *args and a dictionary merge for default values.
In fact my answer offers flexibility and dynamic handling of various scenarios.  Maybe answer the question if you are going to simply nitpick answers.
